# How to open PDF using Adobe reader DC installed with PlayOnLinux

Tags: pdf, playonlinux

How to open PDF using Adobe reader DC installed with PlayOnLinux (when I double click on the PDF file)? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Do not double click. That will open it with the default software which is *not* the (emulated Windows) Adobe Reader software. Open the software you want and then file > open as usual. If you want to make the (Windows) Adobe Reader the default for PDFs (bad idea) you can right-click, open with..., select the desired app and make it the default.

Comment: @MichaelBay yes the second solution is what I want, how should I open with in this case? I can’t find an appropriate one is the open with list.